# gawk use to replace a line containing a pattern with multiple lines using variable

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am trying to replace a line containing the Pattern using `gawk`, with a set of lines. Let's say, file `aa` contains

```
aaaa
ccxyzcc
aaaa
ddxyzdd
```

I'm using gawk to replace all lines containing xyz with a set of lines 111\n222, my changed contents would contain:

```
aaaa
111
222
aaaa
111
222
```

But, if I use:

```
gawk -v nm2="111\n222" -v nm1="xyz" '{ if (/nm1/) print nm2;else print $0}' "aa"
```

The changed content shows:

```
aaaa
ccxyzcc
aaaa
ddxyzdd
```

I need the entire lines those contain `xyz` i.e. lines `ccxyzcc` and `ddxyzdd` having to be replaced with `111` followed by `222`. Please help.

Comment: with `/nm1/` you are trying to match the literal string "nm1". That's why you have to say `$0 ~ nm1` to match the content of the variable `nm1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code was that `/nm1/` tries to match `nm1` as pattern not the value in `nm1` variable

```
$ gawk -v nm2="111\n222" -v nm1="xyz" '$0 ~ nm1{print nm2; next} 1' aa
aaaa
111
222
aaaa
111
222
```

Thanks @fedorqui for suggestion, `next` can be avoided by simply overwriting content of input line matching the pattern with required text

```
gawk -v nm2="111\n222" -v nm1="xyz" '$0 ~ nm1{$0=nm2} 1' aa
```

Solution with GNU `sed`

```
$ nm1='xyz'
$ nm2='111\n222'
$ sed "/$nm1/c $nm2" aa
aaaa
111
222
aaaa
111
222
```

The `c` command would delete the line matching pattern and add the text given

Comment: Nice! You can also say `$0 ~ nm1 {$0=nm2}1` so that `next` is not necessary.

Comment: And code golfing a bit more with a ternary operator: `gawk -v nm2="111\n222" -v nm1="xyz" '{print $0~nm1 ? nm2 : $0}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

When using `awk's` `~` operator, and you don't need to provide a literal regex on the right-hand side.

Your command as-such with the correction of improper syntax would be something like,

```
gawk -v nm2="111\n222" -v nm1="xyz" '{ if ( $0 ~ nm1 ) print nm2;else print $0}' input-file
```

which produces the output.

```
aaaa
111
222
aaaa
111
222
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

```
$ cat aa
aaaa
ccxyzcc
aaaa
ddxyzdd
$ awk '{gsub(/.*xyz.*/, "111\n222")}1' aa
aaaa
111
222
aaaa
111
222
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables as patterns to awk is always a bit tricky.

```
awk  -v nm2='111\n222'  '{if ($1 ~ /xyz/){ print nm2 } else {print}}'
```

will give you the output, but the 'xyz' pattern is now fixed.

Passing nm1 as shell variable will also work:

```
nm1=xyz
awk  -v nm2='111\n222'  '{if ($1 ~ /'$nm1'/){ print nm2 } else {print}}' aa
```